# how to create conditionals in a Fixpoint definition Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am working through the book "Software Foundations", and am on the last problem in Chapter two. The problem asks to convert a natural number into a binary number, where a binary number is defined in the following ways:

```
  - [is] zero,
  - [is] twice a binary number, or
  - [is] one more than twice a binary number.
```

My thought process is that if a natural number is even, then it can be expressed as

```
double(nat_to_bin n)
```

However, in my Fixpoint definition, when I tried to write

```
(evenb n' = true) => double(nat_to_bin)
```

I got an error because evenb n' is not a constructor of nat. Is there any way for me to create a conditional such that the above line would be a valid function definition, without changing the definition of nat?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I figured out a solution. I can just write the term

```
match (evenb n') with
| true => ....
```

Took me a while, though.

Comment: or `if evenb n' then ... else ...`